# How to enable channel URL and not have EE use template group?

Tags: channel, url

I have a channel named Contact, that will hold basic contact information.

The channel fields for this group I have is short list of a few input text fields and one textarea. The template group I have is a template that holds standard content for most pages, also called Page Content.

I have manually entered the url for the Contact channel, adding contact to end of my site's url.

[image]

Of course, when I navigate to this page right, I am getting a 404. I am able to access the page by going to http://mysite.com/page-content/contact.

How do I remove the first segment and have EE load the particular channel URL I have specified for this channel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Channel URL** setting is intended to mark the URL of the channel itself, not of just one of its entries.

You should use the [Pages Module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/pages/index.html) for this.

Comment: Thanks Robson! I have had a look at Pages and Structure to help sort this out